# Circular structure to JSON when deploying

Tags: json, deployment, server, typeerror, circular-reference

Recently, code that I wrote was being deployed to our server, and an error was thrown during deployment that would appear to be my fault.

---

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'SourceFileObject'
property 'statements' -> object with constructor'Array'
index0 -> object with constructor 'NodeObject'
---property 'parent' closes the circle
at stringify(<anonymous>)
at writeChannelMessage (node:internal/child_process/serialization: 127:20)
at process.target.send(node:internal/child_process:819:17)
at process.target.send(node:internal/child_process:719:19)
at process.send(/*project*/*projectname*/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainer.js:51:21)
at process.uncaughtListener(/*project*/*projectname*/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainer.js:275:19
at process.emit(node:events:402:35)
at process.emit(node:domain:475:12)
at process.emit.sharedData.processEmitHook.installedValue [as emit] (/*project*/*projectname*/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/@cspotcode/source-map-support/source-map-support.js745:40)
at process_fatalException(node:internal/process/execution:164:25)
```

---

I have been told to fix this, but I can't reproduce any error in my local.  I can't post the  code, but it is an express backend with a few apis.  I know what a circular reference is, and I don't believe I have any in my code, so, just curious if anyone can help me narrow my search at all.  Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We were able to get a longer version of the error, and it pointed to an import with an incorrect capital letter.  No error in local, but a complicated error during deployment.  Hope this helps someone in the future.